# Что такое telnet и для чего его используют?

Tags: c, c++, telnet

Что такое telnet, для чего его используют, и главное, как его использовать в C/C++?

Comment: Терминальный протокол поверх TCP. Изначально -- rfc854 (потом -- масса расширений,  дополнений и аналогичных протоколов). В настоящее время практически вытеснен протоколом ssh

Comment: Думаю, имеет смысл определение внести в описание метки, а вопрос закрыть.

Answer (score 1):

telnet - протокол канального уровня модели OSI, используемый для связи "терминал - терминал", "процесс - терминал", "процесс - процесс".

Может быть использован практически в любом обеспечении, так что отношение к Си все-таки имеет. Почитайте спецификацию на счет портов и заголовков. Вот маленький кусок [информации](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet).

Comment: Он имеет ровно такое же отношение к си, как и к любому другому ЯП, поэтому и написано что именно к си никакого отношения не имеет, т.к. это всего лиш указания как работать и с чем.

Comment: Это протокол прикладного уровня, а не канального!